# base64 decode as save as multiple files

Tags: bash, files, perl, base64

I have a file(har file saved from web developer" that contains the base64 encoded value of multiple video*.ts files. I am interested to decode the base64 part and save as multiple ts files if the request url is a .ts file and the response encoding should be base64.

```
"request": {
          "bodySize": 0,
          "method": "GET",
          "url": "https://vz-73062248-092.b-cdn.net/856d96e6-97e6-4c3d-82b8-a53a8a411513/1920x1080/video1.ts",
......
.....
....
"response":{

.....
.....
"content": {
            "mimeType": "video/mp2t",
            "size": 882472,
            "encoding": "base64",
"text": "R................=="}, ----->should be decoded from this string as video1.ts
.....
```

The above should be saved as video1.ts , decoded from the base64 string between "text": ", till "

There are multiple entries for the ts files from 1 till 350 in the file. The file is around 500MB

Please please let me know hoe can i save as multiple ts files from the base64 decoded string from the file?

Comment: You nearly have a JSON file. Is it actually a JSON file or is it a broken segment like you show us? If it's a valid JSON file please include enough of the structure so we can use a parser such as `jq` to extract the data

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Comment: So the file is fragments of JSON:  `"key" : { value }` entries not contained in an object?